# tires are moving in a weird way

Tags: animation

im trying to animate my car but the tire rims are rotating wrong but the treads are moving right
[image]

[image: the rims are moving away]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the Rigacar addon? It's what I used to animate my car. It installs widgets that lets you adjust animations for steering, correctly rolling tires, etc without having to adjust piece by piece. It's a bit outdated and there was a slight learning curve to it, but it still worked and saved alot of time for me. If done correctly, it should solve your tire rotation problem, although you may have to go back and adjust a few things. Hope this helps :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3XQxA_-TzY

http://digicreatures.net/articles/rigacar.html